# doble inner join con un count

Tags: mysql

estoy trantando de realizar un doble inner join con un count de otra tabla pero me esta arrojando error de sintaxis mi consulta es la siguiente.

```
SELECT t.idTour as ID,t.fecha as FECHA,COUNT(p.idpasajero) AS 
    pasajeros,t.horario as EVENTO,a.nom_agencia as OPERADOR,t.transporte 
    as TRANSPORTE  
from agencia a left join tour t on t.agencia_idagencia = a.idagencia and INNER join on p.tour_idtour = t.idtour
```

Comment: Intenta borrar `and` antes del `INNER join`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Asumiendo que **p** es **pasajeros** te sobra el operador `and` y te falta la referencia de la tabla **pasajeros** en el `INNER JOIN`

```
SELECT 
  t.idTour as ID,
  t.fecha as FECHA,
  COUNT(p.idpasajero) AS pasajeros,
  t.horario as EVENTO,
  a.nom_agencia as OPERADOR,
  t.transporte as TRANSPORTE  
FROM agencia a 
LEFT JOIN tour t on t.agencia_idagencia = a.idagencia 
INNER JOIN pasajeros p on p.tour_idtour = t.idtour
```

Comment: como puedo usar un group by en el count ya que los pasajeros son fk de tour y tour fk de agencia ?

Comment: me la respondo solo era con un group by al final gracias